# What happens if LEDs do not get enough current?

Tags: power-supply, power, led, current

I'm building a lighting fixture using big led panels.

The LED panel says it requires 7 amps @ 12 volts, but the power supply I have is only rated to 4 amps @12 volts.

What will happen? Will it damage the power supply, or just not light up all the way?

Comment: One of the latter. Try it to find out or better yet, get a suitable power supply.

Comment: Might flash on and off. Might burn out the supply immediately or after a while.

Answer (score 1):

The power supply may be damaged if it does not have over-current protection.  The LEDs should not be damaged, but won't light to full brightness, or will not light at all if the power supply shuts down or fails.

Answer (score 0):

As the current is insufficient, I think the leds will not light up properly or might not light up at all. I don't think there will be any damage to the power supply.

Comment: Since we don’t know the design of the supply, it is also possible that it could overheat and set on fire.